# How do include jQuery in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to include jQuery in my HTML-file but I haven't succeed yet.. I know there are a lot of tutorials and stuff on the internet (and this site!) but it still won't work. 
This is my code in the HTML-file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="global.css"/>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>      
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").css("font-size:50px");
    };
  </script>
<p id="first">Hello there!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I just don't understand why nothing is happening..
Would be awesome if someone could help me with this on!

Comment: did you place the `jquery-2.0.3.min.js` file in the same directory as the source file

Comment: else use the cdn version like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: also to set the css value you need to use `$("p").css("font-size", "50px");`

Comment: You also are missing a `);` closing your DOM ready, which throws syntax error, which bricks your script. Potential cause.

Comment: tymeJV beat me to it..

Comment: Finally got it too work! Thanks a lot for answering my question so quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to close the code properly. You missed the `);`. Also the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method is little different in your version. The parameters should be **property name**, **property value**.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("p").css("font-size","50px");
});
```

Working sample : http://jsbin.com/AfAjihiP/1/

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the jQuery `css()` function quite properly.  You also missed a closing parenthesis.  Try changing it to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css("font-size", "50px");
});
</script>
```

You should always use `.css('property-name', 'property-value')` in that format for best results.  There are other ways (object properties) but they are slightly different syntax and do not conform directly to expected vanilla CSS property names.

[**jQuery API reference - .css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

If that does not fix it, check to be sure your jquery file is in the same directory as the HTML page.  Or (probably better) just replace it with the CDN call recommended by other answers (e.g. replace `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>` in your `head` with `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>`).

Answer (score 1):

There is a small syntax error. Replace:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").css("font-size:50px");
    };
```

With this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("p").css("font-size", "50px");
    });
```

You forgot to close a parenthesis, and the `.css()` function needs two parameters.

Comment: @putvande: I'm sorry, I forgot that the `.css()` function needs two paraters. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do one of two things. You can use the cdn version and link it like this:

or

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script`> after making sure the file is in the root of your project.
also you should have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").css("font-size", "50px");
});
</script>
```

and not what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write several code: Instead of `$(document).ready` use `$` , it works:

so :

```
$(function() {
        $("p").css({"font-size": "50px"});
  });
```

or

```
$(function() {
        $("p").css("font-size", "50px");
});
```